pg_hba.conf for openldap doesn't work. In ldap server two seemingly similar commands have different result. Why?
I'm currently debugging why my postgres database cannot authenticate against openldap (slapd=2.4.57*). In pg_hba.conf I have the following line:
hostssl    all             all             all                     ldap ldapserver=ldap ldapport=389 ldapbasedn="dc=discover,dc=d-fine,dc=com" ldapbinddn="uid=database,ou=users,dc=discover,dc=d-fine,dc=com" ldapbindpasswd=secret ldapsearchattribute=uid ldaptls=1

When I'm in the database container I do the following:
psql "sslmode=require dbname=postgres host=database user=discover-bot"

and get the following error:
psql: error: connection to server at "database" (172.18.0.4), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "discover-bot"

I went to the ldap container to test the connection. At first nothing worked. Then I set the environment variable:
export LDAPTLS_CACERT=/etc/ldap/certs/ca-certs.pem

The following command started to work:
ldapsearch -h ldap -p 389 -ZZ -D "uid=database,ou=users,dc=discover,dc=d-fine,dc=com" -w secret -b "dc=discover,dc=d-fine,dc=com" "(uid=discover-bot)"

But the following command doesn't work:
ldapsearch -x -v -ZZ ldap://ldap:389 -D "uid=database,ou=users,dc=discover,dc=d-fine,dc=com" -w secret -b "dc=discover,dc=d-fine,dc=com" "(uid=discover-bot)".


with error:
ldap_initialize( <DEFAULT> )
ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)
        additional info: (unknown error code)

For some reason in my installation I cannot find detailed logs for LDAP. But maybe the reason for this discrepancy is obvious? Maybe knowing this difference I can format my pg_hba.conf in a different way? Do I need to set LDAPTLS_CACERT in my database or ldap container by default?
UPD. The configuration worked under Debian Buster but not under Debian Bullseye.

When psql fails to connect, what error gets reported in the database log file?  That should be more detailed than what gets reported to the client.

It seems that the simple solution might be to set LDAPTLS_CACERT in the environment of the PostgreSQL server (which acts as LDAP client).

Sorry I'm not able to check these Database logs today. One thing I want to mention is that this configuration worked under Debian Buster but after update to Debian Bullseye the configuration stopped working.

discover-bot@postgres DETAIL:  LDAP diagnostics: (unknown error code)
discover-bot@postgres FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "discover-bot"
discover-bot@postgres DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/etc/postgresql/17/main/pg_hba.conf" line 107: "hostssl    all             all
      all                 ldap ldapserver=ldap ldapport=389 ldapbasedn="dc=discover,dc=d-fine,dc=com" ldapbinddn="uid=database,ou=users,dc=discover,dc=d-fine,dc=com
" ldapbindpasswd=secret ldapsearchattribute=uid ldaptls=1" ````

So basically it matches the right string in pg_hba.conf. I have installed ldapsearch and it successfully  connects to the ldap server and performs the search.

@LaurenzAlbe in my case setting LDAPTLS_CACERT in the database container has no effect..

Are you sure that it is set in the environment of PostgreSQL? Do you see the variable in the output of cat /proc/12345/environ | xargs -0 echo, where 12345 is the process ID of the postmaster?

A little bit more background. Due to some historic configuration reasons we were always installing Postgres on top of Debian docker image. This worked for Postgres 12 and Debian Buster. Preforming the same installation and configuration steps for Debian Bullseye/Bookworm lead to this problem. Yesterday, I took the official postgres:17-bullseye image from Dockerhub, configured it with the same certificates, same pg_hba.conf opened the same ports, set the same environment variables and it WORKS. I don't know why. But I guess for us this is a viable solution right now.
